# https Nodejs: how to check status of POST https request?

Tags: node.js

Here is snippet of POST code from Nodejs document about [https module](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_url_options_callback).

```
const https = require('https')

const data = JSON.stringify({
  todo: 'Buy the milk'
})

const options = {
  hostname: 'whatever.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/todos',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`) //<<==is res.statusCode also the same as req.statusCode?

  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.write(data). //upload data with POST request
//<<== check req.statusCode here???
req.end()
```

Here https.request returns an instance of http.ClientRequest class while `res` is returned with callback. If one wants to know the status of POST request, which variable shall be checked? `req` or `res` or both? BTW are `req` and `res` the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your callback function, `res.statusCode` should give you the status code of your POST request.

Your `req` variable will be a `http.ClientRequest` object which represents an in-progress request so you won't be able to get the status code from that.